# Getting date for calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am a new user of Power BI and I was wondering if it is possible to calculate the date difference that is present in two different tables but they both are connected to the third table in which I want to create a measure or a column using dax to calculate date difference:

[image]

The columns marked in red are dates and I want their difference to be calculated in the assumption table. I used the month number to build the relationship between these tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Measure as below-

```
date_diff = 
DATEDIFF(
    RELATED(d_nl[notification]), 
    RELATED(d_fc[file_closure_date]), 
    DAY
)
```

To know about other Intervals rather than DAY, you can visit [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax).

Comment: related function is not recognizing the d_nl[notification] parameter and same goes for D_fc[file_closure_date]

Comment: Do you have relation established between 3 tables?

Comment: yes i have mentioned in my query above that i am building the relationship between these three tables using month number

Comment: Ok, can you provide some sample data from all 3 tables? That case I can test here.